# How to reset navigation in expo router

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I have 3 screens for forgot password. Forgot password screen starts from login page. So after successfully resetting the password I need user to go to login page. But still the user can go back to the last screen of forgot password from login page when use `router.push()` How to reset the stack navigation with expo router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { useNavigation } from 'expo-router';
const ForgotPasswordScreeen = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation()

    const onResetPassword = () => {
        resetPassword() // your logic to reset the password.
        //This will reset your stack back to login screen
        navigation.reset({
            index: 0,
            routes: [{ name: 'login' }], // your stack screen name
        });
    }

    return (
        <JSX />
    )
}
```

Check the links. Expo-router is a wrapper of react-navigation. I assume you can do everything you can do with react-navigation with expo-router.

https://docs.expo.dev/router/reference/hooks/#usenavigation

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop#reset